# why ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring takes more time

Tags: mount, security, encryption, ecryptfs

I have been trying to encrypt an empty directory. Which involves three steps.

Step 1.Read the key from user and wrap the pass phrase using

```
time printf  "%s\n%s" <user key> <wrap phrase> | ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase <tmp wrap file> -
```

Step 2.Insert the key into kernel key ring using

```
time echo -n <wrap phrase> |  ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring <tmp wrap file>
```

Step 3. Execute mount command

```
time mount -i -t ecryptfs /tmp/folder /tmp/folder  -o with necessary options
```

Step 1 - Is taking 4secs

Step 2 - Is taking 12secs

Step 3 - Is taking 141ms

Can anyone please explain why step1 and step2 are taking more time ?
Is there anyway to optimize this ?

Thanks in Advance
Murali Marimekala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands all do very different things and they're not expected to execute in similar amounts of time.

Step #3 is completely bypassing the eCryptfs userspace since you're using the -i option of mount.

Step #1 and #2 are doing CPU intensive operations to ensure that the passphrase-based keys are not easily brute forced. Key stretching or key strengthing are common terms describing the process.

Step #1 performs key stretching on one passphrase.

Step #2 performs key stretching on 3 passphrases. This is the result of an unfortunate mistake introduced when the encrypted home support was originally implemented. Key stretching is really only needed on what you refer to as the "wrap passphrase" but it is also happening on the fekek (file encryption key encryption key) and fnek (filename encryption key). This behavior has been preserved for backwards compatibility and while it could be fixed in the future, there are currently no plans to fix it. We'd certainly entertain someone contributing patches to the upstream project to fix it in a way that doesn't break backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Tyhicks for the clarification. Sorry, I couldn't understand the last paragraph. Overall I understand is #2 involves key stretching of fekek and fnek which are not necessary but they are in place because to make them backward compatible with older versions. This key stretching is taking time and performing cpu intensive work. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited my answer to make it more clear but it sounds like you already have a good understanding of what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks Tyhicks. Its makes sense now why #2 is taking more time.